# Turtle circle shape in a main GUI TK

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

First of all, thanks for stopping by into my post. I'm a amateur Python writer. Right now, I'm writing a code that will control some Agilent instruments, into my GUI I need to display a virtual LED that can show to the operator the current test progress status, like, yellow = testing, green = passed, red= failed.

I found that turtle module can easily create a circle by adding turtle.shape('cicle'), please see below a turtle code I have:

I want to make it clear, I did not wrote the below code, I found the code in this webpage.

```
    from turtle import Screen, Turtle

    CURSOR_SIZE = 30

    def blink():
        pen, fill = turtle.color()
        turtle.color(fill, pen)
        screen.ontimer(blink, 500)  # 1/4 second blink

    screen = Screen()

    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.shape('circle')
    turtle.shapesize(50 / CURSOR_SIZE)
    turtle.color('red', 'Yellow')
    turtle.showturtle()

    blink()
```

So, I want to place the button into my main GUI window:

```
    ########## Main Window Design##########
    main = Tk()
    main.geometry('860x500+65+0')
    main.title('Firmware Upgrade System 1.0')
    Label(main,text='Firmware Upgrade System 1.0', font=("Tahoma", 20)).place(x=0,y=0)


    ##! UUT 1 ####################################
    LabelFrame(main, text=' UUT 1 INFORMATION : ', font=("Tahoma", 10), height=120, width=420, bd=2, relief='groove' ).place(x=10,y=40)
    LabelFrame(main, text='Serial Number',font=("Tahoma", 10), height=47, width=110, bd=3, relief='ridge').place(x=13,y=60)
    LabelFrame(main, text='Firmware Version',font=("Tahoma", 10), height=47, width=119, bd=3, relief='ridge').place(x=126,y=60)

    def fw_upgrade():
        print("pas")
        blink()

    #######Buttons and Functions
    Button(main, text="FIRMWARE UPGRADE", font=("Tahoma", 12), height=1, width=20, command=fw_upgrade).place(x=450,y=440)
```

So, every time I execute the code, it opens a secondary window with the virtual LED. How to incorporate into my main GUI?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

The regular `Turtle` and `Screen` always create a new window.

The turtle module has another `RawTurtle` class which works exactly the same as `Turtle`, but draws on an existing `tk.Canvas`, `turtle.TurtleScreen` or `turtle.Screen` instance that you must provide. [Take a look at the turtle docs, they have lots of examples too](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.RawTurtle)

You should also call `mainloop()` on the `Tk()` window at the end of your code so that the window stays open.
(It's also a good idea to store the instances of your LabelFrames and all the widgets in variables if you're likely to change any of their properties or text later on)

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, LabelFrame, Button, Canvas
from turtle import TurtleScreen, RawTurtle

def fw_upgrade():
    print("pas")

########## Main Window Design##########
main = Tk()
main.geometry('860x500+65+0')
main.title('Firmware Upgrade System 1.0')
label1 = Label(main,text='Firmware Upgrade System 1.0', font=("Tahoma", 20))
label1.place(x=0,y=0)
##! UUT 1 ####################################
frame1 = LabelFrame(main, text=' UUT 1 INFORMATION : ', font=("Tahoma", 10), height=120, width=420, bd=2, relief='groove' )
frame1.place(x=10,y=40)
frame2 = LabelFrame(main, text='Serial Number',font=("Tahoma", 10), height=47, width=110, bd=3, relief='ridge')
frame2.place(x=13,y=60)
frame3 = LabelFrame(main, text='Firmware Version',font=("Tahoma", 10), height=47, width=119, bd=3, relief='ridge')
frame3.place(x=126,y=60)
btn = Button(main, text="FIRMWARE UPGRADE", font=("Tahoma", 12), height=1, width=20, command=fw_upgrade)
btn.place(x=450,y=440)

canv = Canvas(main)
turtlescr = TurtleScreen(canv)
canv.place(x=0, y=100)

CURSOR_SIZE = 30
turtle = RawTurtle(turtlescr)
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.shapesize(50 / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.color('red', 'Yellow')
turtle.showturtle()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you @gdcodes what you have described works and moved the "circle" into my GUI, however, the window generated by Turtle obstructed my GUI, what I'm trying to do is to add a virtual led that I can change color during the execution of my test.  Please see the following link is a National Instruments picture of a test in progress showing an GRENN virtual LED blinking during the execution of the test https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Code/NI-TestStand-Featured-Examples/ta-p/3996417?profile.language=en